# Setting up web-facing home server for jupyter on windows

Tags: networking, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook running on Windows that I'd like to be able to access remotely through https. I'm a novice when it comes to computer networking and would appreciate if anyone knew how to set this up. How would i secure a web-facing ip-address and setup my jupyter notebook to forward to that ip-address. I definitely need to run computation off of my home machine rather than something like an ec2 instance because my system is setup with gpu-acceleration for tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading through the [docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html)?